# Allow one of many encryption/signature algorithms for single public key certificate

Tags: encryption, signature, pgp

Let's say a user creates their primary gpg key pair for `User Name <user@email.com>` and selects an encryption and signing algorithm that isn't widely available (think goldilocks). For instance, let's say one would create a signing key with ed448, and encryption key with cv448.

If the user goes ahead and submits such a key certificate to key servers, I would imagine most individuals won't be able to send them encrypted communications or verify their signature. So, a few related questions:

1. Would adding another encryption subkey for a widely used encryption standard like RSA before submitting the key certificate to keyservers help the situation (more people will be able to encrypt for the user)?
2. If 1. is true, will gpg automatically choose the strongest encryption algorithm at senders end (depending on if they have goldilocks or just RSA)? Or will the sender have to explicitly  specify RSA/goldilocks subkey for encryption or just identify the user with their primary public key?
3. Similarly, can such a user sign the same data with two different keys (RSA and ed-goldilocks)? Will it be two different certificates or can it be captured in one? Would gpg automatically choose the strongest signature verification algorithm at the recipient's end?

I tried finding answers to these questions but couldn't find anything. Most similar questions are about encryption/signing for multiple different recipients.

Comment: This is more related to [security.se] as most key management questions are handled at [security.se]. Do you mind if I migrate it to that site? You need to also sign in there to interact with your question. Here it could be closed as off topic.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes-modelection Sure, thanks for the information! I am new to information security and crypto systems.